# listar archivos en un directorio con codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

No logro listar un directorio en codeiniter, solo necesito los nombres de los archivos, antes lo hacía así:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
    $path="servicios/"; //directorio a listar
    $directorio=dir($path);

$pn= array();//pila de nombres
$pf= array();//pila de fechas
$pt= array();//pila de tamaNos

while ($archivo = $directorio->read()){

$archivo1="servicios/".$archivo;

if(file_exists($archivo1)){
if(($archivo!='index.php')&&($archivo!='.')&&($archivo!='..')){
array_push($pn, $archivo);
array_push($pf, date("d F Y H:i", filemtime($archivo1)));
array_push($pt, filesize($archivo1));
}
}
else
    {
        echo 'no existe' ;
        //var_dump($archivo);
    }
}
$directorio->close();

array_multisort($pn,SORT_DESC,$pf,$pt);
for($i=0; $i<count($pn); $i++){
    echo "<a href='servicios/".$pn[$i]."'>".$pn[$i]."</a>";
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
    echo " <b>fecha:</b>".$pf[$i];
//echo '<a href="servicios/'.$pn[$i].'">'.$pn[$i]."</a><b>fecha:</b>".$pf[$i];
printf(" <b>peso:</b>%1.3fKb<br>\n",$pt[$i]/1000);
}
```

luego intenté con la función de codeigniter:

```
$map = directory_map('./mydirectory/');
```

al directorio lo puese en la raíz y también en la misma carpeta de la vista para probar pero siempre muestra null

Answer (score 0):

Para que esta función se lleve a cabo debes de importar el helper:

```
$this->load->helper('directory');
```

Se crea la variable que se convertirá en un arreglo:

```
$map = directory_map('./mydirectory/');
```

Y recorriendo ese arreglo con un foreach podrás ver su contenido y te quedara algo como esto:

```
Array (
    [libraries] => Array
        (
            [0] => benchmark.html
            [1] => config.html
            ["database/"] => Array
                    (
                            [0] => query_builder.html
                            [1] => binds.html
                            [2] => configuration.html
                            [3] => connecting.html
                            [4] => examples.html
                            [5] => fields.html
                            [6] => index.html
                            [7] => queries.html
                    )
            [2] => email.html
            [3] => file_uploading.html
            [4] => image_lib.html
            [5] => input.html
            [6] => language.html
            [7] => loader.html
            [8] => pagination.html
            [9] => uri.html
    )
```

Para más información puedes ir a la [documentación](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/index.html) de `Codeigniter` respecto a [Directory Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/directory_helper.html).

Comment: gracias javier por tu respuesta . pero si lo hice y nada . lo que pienso es que el problema esta en los permisos en el .htacces pero la verdad no se como darle los permisos, como para probar

Comment: no entiendo ¿porque modificar el htaccess? si codeigniter te lo permite por si solo.

Comment: no yo no lo modifico. solo se me ocurrio que hay esta el problema